# Why will Dajjal come from Iran?

Tags: hadith, hadith-interpretation, theology, dajjal

As we know Dajjal will come from Khorasan. [Chapter: The tribulation of Dajjal, the emergence of 'Esa bin Maryam and the emergence of Gog and Magog, Sunan Ibn Majah](https://sunnah.com/ibnmajah:4072) and he will be followed by 70,000 jews from Ispahan [Chapter: The Rest Of The Ahadith About Ad-Dajjal, Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:2944). But according to history, Assyrian's exiled the people of Kingdom of Israel which are 10 Lost tribes(Asher, Dan, Ephraim, Gad, Issachar, Manasseh, Naphtali, Reuben, Simeon, and Zebulun). Jews are expecting their king messiah from the progeny of David(PBUH) and the tribe of david was Judah from the southern kingdom of Judah(Which includes the tribes Judah and Benjamin). If dajjal come from area near Khorasan then he must be from the 10 tribes and historically the persian jews are not from the tribes of Judah [The “Persian” Period](https://www.oxfordbibliographies.com/view/document/obo-9780195393361/obo-9780195393361-0194.xml). How the islamic theologians and scholars explain this dillema? I am studying the comparative theology for last 2 years. Can someone help me in this particular matters?

Answer (score 1):

Good question, now look what Jesus says in the New Testament:

**Matthew 22**

> 41 While the Pharisees were gathered together, Jesus asked them,
>
> 42 Saying, What think ye of Christ? whose son is he? **They say unto him, The Son of David.**
>
> 43 He saith unto them, How then doth David in spirit call him Lord, saying,
>
> 44 The LORD said unto my Lord, Sit thou on my right hand, till I make thine enemies thy footstool?
>
> 45 If David then call him Lord, how is he his son?

Jesus is actually asking the Jews:

> *How do you say the Messiah is the son of David [i.e. Isaiah 11] when David calls the Messiah "My Master"? [i.e. Psalm 110]*

This means:

1. The Jews corrupted the book of Isaiah.
2. Jesus is not the son of David.
3. The Anti-Christ is a real figure [whom Christians doubt].

The appearance of Anti-Christ from Persia means that the Jews today [whom majority exist in Palestine now] will be exiled there as a last resort before their saviour comes.

I'm talking about this Hadeeth:

> وعن أبي هريرة رضي الله عنه أن رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم قال‏:‏ ‏ "‏ لا تقوم الساعة حتى يقاتل المسلمون اليهود، حتى يختبيء اليهودي من وراء الحجر والشجر، فيقول الحجر والشجر‏:‏ يا مسلم هذا يهودي خلفى تعالى فاقتله، إلا الغرقد فإنه من شجر اليهود‏"
>
> The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said, "The Last Hour will not come **until the Muslims fight against the Jews,** until a Jew will hide himself behind a stone or a tree, and the stone or the tree will say: 'O Muslim, there is a Jew behind me. Come and kill him,' but Al-Gharqad tree will not say so, for it is the tree of the Jews."

This is irrelevant to the appearance of Anti-Christ, what's relevant is Armageddon, the future war between Christians and Muslims:

> حَدَّثَنَا عَبَّاسٌ الْعَنْبَرِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا هَاشِمُ بْنُ الْقَاسِمِ، حَدَّثَنَا عَبْدُ الرَّحْمَنِ بْنُ ثَابِتِ بْنِ ثَوْبَانَ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ مَكْحُولٍ، عَنْ جُبَيْرِ بْنِ نُفَيْرٍ، عَنْ مَالِكِ بْنِ يُخَامِرَ، عَنْ مُعَاذِ بْنِ جَبَلٍ، قَالَ قَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏ "‏ عُمْرَانُ بَيْتِ الْمَقْدِسِ خَرَابُ يَثْرِبَ وَخَرَابُ يَثْرِبَ خُرُوجُ الْمَلْحَمَةِ وَخُرُوجُ الْمَلْحَمَةِ فَتْحُ قُسْطَنْطِينِيَّةَ وَفَتْحُ الْقُسْطَنْطِينِيَّةِ خُرُوجُ الدَّجَّالِ ‏"
>
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said: The flourishing state of Jerusalem will be when Yathrib is in ruins, the ruined state of Yathrib will be when the great war comes, the outbreak of the great war will be at the conquest of Constantinople **and the conquest of Constantinople when the Dajjal (Antichrist) comes forth.**

We also know that Jesus is [actually] the son of Levi, not David:

19:28
يَـٰٓأُخْتَ هَـٰرُونَ مَا كَانَ أَبُوكِ ٱمْرَأَ سَوْءٍ وَمَا كَانَتْ أُمُّكِ بَغِيًّا

> ***O sister [i.e., descendant] of Aaron,** your father was not a man of evil, nor was your mother unchaste.*

The Bible proves that too by linking the Virgin Mary with Elisabeth, the wife of Prophet Zeckariah [AS]:

> Luke 1:36 And behold, **thy cousin Elizabeth,** she hath also conceiued a sonne in her old age, and this is the sixt moneth with her, who was called barren.

And both of Zeckariah and Elisabeth were Levites:

> Luke 1:5 ¶ There was in the dayes of Herode the king of Iudea, a certaine Priest, named Zacharias, of the course of Abia, **and his wife was of the daughters of Aaron, and her name was Elizabeth.**

So Jesus and his family were all Levites, like Prophet Moses and Aaron!

This is [of course] blasphemous against Christianity, since Christians believe that Jesus can not be the Messiah if he is not David's son, but the Jews started this mess and Christians continued the same path and ruined it for worse:

5:48
وَلَـٰكِن لِّيَبْلُوَكُمْ فِى مَآ ءَاتَىٰكُمْ ۖ فَٱسْتَبِقُوا۟ ٱلْخَيْرَٰتِ

> ***But to test you** in what He has given you; so race to [all that is] good.*

To an extent, Jesus never told the Jews that he is their Moshiach or saviour in either the Qur'an or the NT, it's the Jews who predicted that Jesus wants to take authority over them and hence; saw a perfect formula for a Messiah claimant:

4:157
وَقَوْلِهِمْ إِنَّا قَتَلْنَا ٱلْمَسِيحَ عِيسَى ٱبْنَ مَرْيَمَ رَسُولَ ٱللَّهِ

> *And [for] their saying, "**Indeed, we have killed the Messiah,** Jesus the son of Mary, the messenger of Allah."*

All what we can say is the truth will reveal itself with time, also check the Hadeeth of Tamim Al-Daree, it mentions interesting details about that false Christ: https://sunnah.com/muslim:2942a

**Note:** The Hadeeth mentions the Anti-Christ will appear from the east, but captured in an isolated island [not Persia], and this doesn't contradict the Hadeeth that he will start his preach from Persia, not that he is captured there.

Comment: Ok, But problem still remains as the follower of dajjal will be the jews. Ya, You talked about a future exile, but most scholar link the hadith about war with jews with the last phrase of Armageddon which is the fight against dajjal. Yes, According to some scholar, There is a possibility of future exile of jews in quran 17:5-8. Allah knows best. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just like to mention another interesting point here. According to jews escatology, they expecting a messiah ben joseph before messiah ben david. The messiah ben joseph will be from epharim who are belongs to lost 10 tribes. This messiah ben joseph will visit arround the world to gather the 10 tribes to israel and finally die before the messiah ben david come(Ezekiel 39-40). Dajjal will also visit around the world.

Comment: Is it possible that he initially declare himself the messiah ben joseph then when his power and popularity grow up, he will declare himself the king messiah and finally call himself Allah(Nauzubillah)?

Comment: Well, I checked an explanation to the Hadeeth, and you are correct: https://www.dorar.net/hadith/sharh/61547 , although it doesn't mean the Caliphate will not turn back before the appearance of Mahdi. My understanding to [17:5-8] is the first was the conquest of Nebuchadnezzar to Jerusalem, [17:4] makes a future prophecy about the Israeli state just like Daniel 11:45. And in Ezekiel 33:23-29, Allah threatens the Jews to take the Holy Land from them if they transgress, which confirms the Qur'an.

Comment: The Anti-Christ will be sanctified by the Jews in the same way the Christians worship Jesus, each one of them will worship their own god, and that's why Prophet Muhammad urged the Companions about Dajjal: "Your Lord is not one-eyed!" ربكم ليس بأعور. The modern day Jews say the Moshiach is a normal human being [so that none compares them to Christians], but they clearly don't know him: https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1814 , their eschatology about ben David is incorrect as Jesus is not a Judean + They are not certain of ben Joseph since his prophecies aren't from the Hebrew Bible.

Comment: Yap, Thanks for the discussion. I will up vote once I have enough reputation to able to give the vote

Comment: You don't need, I upvoted your post since I like studying the scripture, also look for El-Da3wa channel: https://www.youtube.com/c/eld3wah/playlists and Al-Dorar encyclopedia: https://dorar.net/adyan , both will give you extensive information for Christianity and Judaism, but from an Islamic view. A must for Bible study.

Answer (score -1):

With a brief look at the collection of narrations that have been narrated about the departure of the Antichrist and related events, we come across several topics and headings, all of which require in-depth and extensive research.
Most of the narrations narrated by the Sunnis about the Antichrist and his characteristics are due to the weakness of the document or myth-making and the expression of strange and far-fetched things.
Some contemporary writers have doubted the existence of the Antichrist or his characteristics and finally believed in the mystery and irony of the characteristics of the Antichrist and the incompatibility of these characteristics with a specific person or being. So it is not possible to say with certainty what the Antichrist is and where he comes from. I do not know how you say with certainty that the Antichrist comes from Iran ?!
In the end, the Antichrist is probably not a person, but a civilized intellectual movement that is hostile to Islam! The concept of the Antichrist is the symbol of the most complex and dangerous enemy of Islam and God, and this is in fact the description and materialist worldview of the West. The characteristics mentioned in the narrations for the Antichrist have a strange resemblance to televisions and mobile phones. An eye that has a distance between their ears and thousands of sounds and media are broadcast in different languages to enchant everyone and bring them with them.

https://www.porseman.com/article/%D8%A2%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%AA-%D8%AF%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%88%D8%AF%D9%8A%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B5%D9%81%D9%87%D8%A7%D9%86-%D8%AE%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%AC-%D8%AE%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%87%D8%AF-%D9%83%D8%B1%D8%AF%D8%9F/156026

https://www.mehrnews.com/news/5043526/%D8%AF%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%84-%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%B3%D8%AA-%D9%88-%DA%86%DA%AF%D9%88%D9%86%D9%87-%DA%A9%D8%B4%D8%AA%D9%87-%D9%85%DB%8C-%D8%B4%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A8%D8%B2%D8%B1%DA%AF-%D8%AA%D8%B1%DB%8C%D9%86-%D9%81%D8%AA%D9%86%D9%87-%D8%A2%D8%AE%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B2%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86